# Rails - Split integer form field into 3 separate sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a time field which stores an integer(minutes). I want the user to be able to enter in days, hours and minutes in the form rather than entering minutes.

```
.form-group
    = f.label :time, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.text_field :time, class: "form-control"
```

Is there an easy way to do this via the form so that I would have...?

```
.form-group
    = f.label :days, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.text_field :days, class: "form-control"
.form-group
    = f.label :hours, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.text_field :hours, class: "form-control"
.form-group
    = f.label :minutes, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.text_field :minutes, class: "form-control"
```

I realise I could just have days,hours and minutes as database fields but I'd rather just keep my single time field.

Comment: try implementing `days`, `hours`, and `minutes` methods in a model (or presenter/decorator)  to use them in form. probably you additionally have to implement assign methods too.

Answer (score 1):

Came across a similar situation, this is what helped me.
[gem time_splitter](https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter)

Looks like this will accomplish the job for you as well, simply runs on top of whatever datetime fields you have for your model.

Comment: that looks good but I don't need an actual date just x days, I'll have to just add the individual fields to the model

Comment: for days field see  [time_splitter - Allow year, month and day selectors](https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter/issues/11)  and this [commit9bbf6a082b..](https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter/pull/12/commits/9bbf6a082b0320d5fbc724342220e0f5438e698f)

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the time field and have your days, hours and minutes field showing and use javascript to calculate the time in minutes based on the values provided on the fields that are showing and just submit that.

so it would be something like (and this is pseudo code):

`time.value = (days.value * 1440) + (hours.value * 60) + minutes.value.`